# Change gridView position WinRT Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

How can I move the position displayed into a GridView ?

On Windows 8 with WinRT.

I try the method ScrollIntoView of my gridview but seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just taking a guess here, but you have to wait until the grid is [loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=win.10%29.aspx) before you can call the `ScrollIntoView` method.

Sample code:

```
public MyPageConstructor()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.itemGridView.Loaded += (s,e) => itemGridView_Loaded(s, e);
}

private void itemGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myobject = // get object
    this.itemGridView.ScrollIntoView(myobject);
}
```